# Regular expression chain multiple conditions

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression which is replacing all of the opening except for `<b></b>` tags, which it ignores. How would I also add an expression to ignore `<i></i>` tags?

```
/<(?!\/?b(?=>|\s.*>))\w[^>]*>/gm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<(?!\/?[bi](?=>|\s.*>))\w[^>]*>` regex.

`[bi]` means ***either 'b' or 'i'***.